# How to setup WebAPI Controller to accept both model data and files in single POST request?

Tags: c#, http, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-apicontroller

I need to setup a Web API controller to accept both a model and a file in a single POST. While I have seen plenty of Stack Overflow posts regarding this issue, mine is slightly different. To frame my situation a little better, I am essentially attempting to mimic the behavior of MailGun's API. Their [API Documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples) provides a client example in RestSharp that POSTs what is essentially a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object or model as well as attachment files. I have already edited the WebApiConfig to accept multipart/form-data with this line: `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));`.

When I run the client application, I do enter into the Post Method (Break Point Check) however, the Message m is null. Is there a way to automatically map the parameters to the Message model via a multipart/form-data request, similar to an application/json request? I can manually parse the request headers to get all the info I need, but that feels hacky and not correct. Do I need to do some sort of Model or Parameter Binding?

Another key point of this is that I am attempting to use the summary comments as the documentation in API's Help Screen. I have that setup already. I did not include the summary comments here to avoid the clutter. I want a way to show the model as a required body parameter, or I would just settle for the manual parsing of the request.

Here is a basic representation of what I have so far:

```
[Route("api/{domain}/messages")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string domain, [FromBody]Message m)
{
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

And my client (should basically mimic the MailGun example):

```
public static IRestResponse TestPostFileAndData()
{
  RestClient client = new RestClient();
  client.BaseUrl = new Uri("<LOCALHOST>/api");
  RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
  request.AddParameter("domain", "<DOMAIN>", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
  request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
  request.AddFile("file", FILE_PATH);
  request.AddParameter("from", "<SENDER>");
  request.AddParameter("to", "<RECIPIENT_1>");
  request.AddParameter("to", "<RECIPIENT_2>");
  request.AddParameter("subject", "SUBJECT_LINE");
  request.AddParameter("text", "TEXT_BODY");
  request.Method = Method.POST;
  return client.Execute(request);
}
```

And my Message Model:

```
public class Message
{
    public string from { get; set; } = "";
    public List<string> to { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public string subject { get; set; } = "";
    public string text { get; set; } = "";
}
```